# Make my smoke less fake

Tags: cycles-render-engine, particles, physics, smoke-simulation

My smoke looks like coming from an electronic cigarette...

I used the particles system to create this smoke.
I tried to play with the density using shader nodes but it's been unefficient.

On which parameters can I play to make it look more detailled like in the second picture?

[image: Takeoff]

[image]

Comment: Try using Noise in Gas settings, it adds more details

Comment: It seems to be a great solution to my issue, thanks a lot! I need a little time to play with the settings before getting the wanted result! Thank you again

Comment: [https://youtu.be/MyV07JnL3DA] here this might help looks a little like it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Try turning on Noise in your domain settings.

Change the Upres Fac to adjust the amount of noise. There's also a Strength and Scale you can adjust.

You could try increasing the Vorticity as well, but it's easy to overdo, so use caution!

[image: Fluid Domain Settings in Blender]

Another way to add more noise is to use a Turbulence force field somewhere in your domain.

(Awesome sim by the way!)

Comment: Thank you! It is really close of what I intented to get! (Thanks :) )